# couldn't install libusb library

Tags: software-installation, noobs, shared-libraries

I'm trying to install a third party library, which has a dependency with `libusb-1.0-0dev` library. Raspberry pi has `NOOBS` setup, which I believe `libusb` library is pre-installed within it. To cross-check the library version, I ran the command.

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libusb
```

It returns a line that shows the `libusb-1.0-0` version installed(not the dev version). As I need `libusb-1.0-0-dev` version, so I tried to install the dev version using this command

```
$ sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

It returned an error,

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/libphidget-2.1.8.20150410 $ sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libusb-1.0-0-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 184 kB of archives.
After this operation, 962 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libusb-1.0-0-dev
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libusb-1.0-0-dev armhf 2:1.0.11-1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libu/libusbx/libusb-1.0-0-dev_1.0.11-1_armhf.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I even tried to run with --fix-missing, but gives the same error. Did anyone come across this issue, or any suggestions on how to install libusb.

Comment: did you do a `sudo apt-get update` before running the `sudo apt-get install`? If you did not, the repository and the information on your rPi might be out of sync, which could cause the above issue.

Answer (score 5):

Try running `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then `sudo apt-get update` **before** running `sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev`.

**Also**

Make sure you are connected to the internet, run `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping google.com` I had a problem a while ago where I could ping IPs but not addresses.

Comment: I did this *sans* `upgrade`

Answer (score -1):

Download libusb debian package for armhf from [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/libusb-1.0-0-dev/download)
and 
on raspberry pi install this package:

```
dpkg -I deb_package_name
```

Verify whether installed correctly or not
/usr/lib/include/libusb-1.0

This has worked for me.